# Is there a special name for expert explanations cognitive biases?

Tags: terminology

Is there a special name of cognitive distortion, when a number of things seem obvious and elementary to an expert, although in reality they are counterintuitive and complex? And therefore his explanations are very difficult to perceive for a person without a background

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What is the name of the cognitive bias where an expert overestimates the knowledge of others?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/3801/7001)